# How to insert key value after a specific Key Value in nested dictionary lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
mydict = {'sequence': [{'name': 'Start 1', 'action': [{'subscribe': {'user': ['user 1', 'user 3'], 'delay': 120}}, {'subscribe': {'user': ['user 2', 'user5'], 'delay': 20}}]}, {'name': 'Start 5', 'action': [{'subscribe': {'user': ['user 6', 'user 7'], 'delay': 100}}, {'subscribe': {'user': ['user 2', 'user5'], 'delay': 80}}]}]}
```

I am trying to insert/append additional 'subscribe' and 'delay' dictionaries to the 'action' list under each 'name' dictionary.
I am having issues being able to reference/identify the correct list 'name' in order to append the 'subscribe' and 'delay'. The subscribe and delay data is coming from different excel sheets with the only linking data being the 'Name'.
Currently using pandas to import the excel data.

```
newdata =  {'subscribe': {'user': ['user X', 'user Y'], 'delay': Z}}

newdata2 =  {'subscribe': {'user': ['user A', 'user B'], 'delay': C}}
```

Final dictionary

```
mydict = {'sequence': [{'name': 'Start 1', 'action': [{'subscribe': {'user': ['user 1', 'user 3'], 'delay': 120}}, {'subscribe': {'user': ['user 2', 'user5'], 'delay': 20}}, {'subscribe': {'user': ['user X', 'user Y'], 'delay': Z}}]}, {'name': 'Start 5', 'action': [{'subscribe': {'user': ['user 6', 'user 7'], 'delay': 100}}, {'subscribe': {'user': ['user 2', 'user5'], 'delay': 80}}, {'subscribe': {'user': ['user A', 'user B'], 'delay': C}}]}]}
```

Is what i am trying to do possible?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 
 Usually it's best to also add what you've tried on top of your question so that other answerers will be more willing to answer. Hope the answer helps, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Given the original data:

```
mydict = {'sequence': 
[ {'name': 'Start 1',
   'action': [{'subscribe': {'user': ['user 1', 'user 3'], 'delay': 120}},
    {'subscribe': {'user': ['user 2', 'user5'], 'delay': 20}}}]},
  {'name': 'Start 5',
   'action': [{'subscribe': {'user': ['user 6', 'user 7'], 'delay': 100}},
    {'subscribe': {'user': ['user 2', 'user5'], 'delay': 80}}}]}
]}
```

With `mydict['sequence'][0]`, you can get:

```
{'name': 'Start 1',
 'action': [{'subscribe': {'user': ['user 1', 'user 3'], 'delay': 120}},
  {'subscribe': {'user': ['user 2', 'user5'], 'delay': 20}}]}
```

And give that you want to add `newdata` to actions in `mydict['sequence'][0]`, you can do

```
mydict['sequence'][0]['action'].append(newdata)
```

Similarly if you want to add `newdata2 to actions in` mydict['sequence'][1]`, you can do:

```
mydict['sequence'][1]['action'].append(newdata2)
```

## TL;DR

```
mydict = {'sequence': [{'name': 'Start 1',
   'action': [{'subscribe': {'user': ['user 1', 'user 3'], 'delay': 120}},
    {'subscribe': {'user': ['user 2', 'user5'], 'delay': 20}}]},
  {'name': 'Start 5',
   'action': [{'subscribe': {'user': ['user 6', 'user 7'], 'delay': 100}},
    {'subscribe': {'user': ['user 2', 'user5'], 'delay': 80}}]}]}


Z = 9999
C = 8888
newdata =  {'subscribe': {'user': ['user X', 'user Y'], 'delay': Z}}
newdata2 =  {'subscribe': {'user': ['user A', 'user B'], 'delay': C}}

mydict['sequence'][0]['action'].append(newdata)
mydict['sequence'][1]['action'].append(newdata2)
```

[out]:

```
[{'name': 'Start 1',
  'action': [{'subscribe': {'user': ['user 1', 'user 3'], 'delay': 120}},
   {'subscribe': {'user': ['user 2', 'user5'], 'delay': 20}},
   {'subscribe': {'user': ['user X', 'user Y'], 'delay': 9999}}]},
 {'name': 'Start 5',
  'action': [{'subscribe': {'user': ['user 6', 'user 7'], 'delay': 100}},
   {'subscribe': {'user': ['user 2', 'user5'], 'delay': 80}},
   {'subscribe': {'user': ['user A', 'user B'], 'delay': 8888}}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm trying to do that but using a k:v search to identify the index.

Comment: Then, you'll need to be a little more specific and explain how you want to "identify the index" and what are `A` and `B` and `X` and `Y`.

Comment: The k:v search is based upon the {'name' : 'value'} key/value, once correctly identify the correct dictionary, then adding the newdata to that 'action'.  The A,B,C,X,Y,Z are value variables.